# Are the MSDN docs for "Working with Strings" not up to date?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am in the beginnings of learning `C++` and the `Win32` API. While using the documentation provided by Microsoft I discovered an issue with one of their examples:

```
wchar_t a = L'a';
wchar_t *str = L"hello";
```

Specifically the last one gives me a compiler error because the expression `L"hello"` produces a `const wchar_t *`.

Is this documentation outdated or is there some config I need to do?

Comment: `wchar_t *str = L"hello";` should be `const wchar_t *str = L"hello";` or `const auto *str = L"hello";`.

Comment: Yes.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance mode = No was the legacy setting.  Goes back to an old mistake in the C98 standard, too much code around that is not const-correct.

Comment: There is no language that goes by the name *"C98"*. There's C99, but you are probably referring to ANSI C, sometimes called *"C89"*.

Comment: @IInspectable - I think Hans meant C++98.

Comment: C++98 did not introduce the *"mistake"* Hans Passant was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are out of date with regard to default string-constness (though this can be changed through project configuration).

They are also out of date in many places with regard to what Unicode is. There are many docs that were written when Unicode was only what is now UCS-2 and have never been updated to post-BMP reality. The docs are still useful you just have to keep in mind the difference between a wchar_t code unit and a Unicode code point.

Comment: That's incorrect. The docs are perfectly correct, even today. They are written against the C programming language, not C++ which you assume. The fact that code sections are erroneously annotated with *"C++"* doesn't help.

Comment: IInspectable: At the time the docs I'm thinking of (which are all part of the windows API documentation set rather than visual c++) neither C or C++ even defined what "Unicode" meant. Unfortunately I haven't been able to dig up an example but in the 4+ million pages of MSDN I am sure they are still there.

Comment: I was referring to `wchar_t *str = L"hello";`. That is perfectly valid C code.

Comment: Doc in question is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings and is correct, but it doesn't discuss the details on how you should configure you C++ compiler to make it work. I guess they or you could add a remark, as the doc itself is now open source and accepts pull requests I believe.